# adding ovelay on a map(objective c)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mapkit

How to add overlay on a map in objective c?
(has any body tried it in iphone os 4.0)?

Comment: what sort of overlay are you trying to add? like a poly-lines route, or something like a HUD of sorts?

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=136) is a good article on using the MKPolyline overlay to add a route type annotation to your map. It should give you an idea how to add any of the other overlays. just implement the

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id )overlay
```

on your map delegate and give it the type of overlay your are drawing.

Comment: im just glad they added it. I had a custom annotation that i used to do the same thing in 3.x and it was slow. having these overlays make things loads easier.